# No Sound on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I have a windows 10 PC which produced sound fine until a couple of days ago.

I have monitor speakers which are fed through the HDMI cable. Going through the windows audio troubleshooter I can hear a test sound but nothing else.

If I plug headphones in they work perfectly.

Things I have tried:

- Restarting.
- Reinstalling Graphics Drivers.
- Confirming that I am using the correct playback device.
- Windows Audio Troubleshooter.
- Running Windows Updates.
- Turned off Audio Enhancements.

Comment: *Reinstalling Audio Drivers*, what drivers? Audio on HDMI has nothing to do with the sound card or its drivers, the ones driving your headphones (or anything else connected to the analogue audio outputs), it's integrated on the graphics card and depends on the graphics card drivers.

Comment: TIL Thank you. My Graphics Card Drivers are out of date. I will update them now just in case.

Comment: if your monitor has a headphone jack, you might try that.

Comment: If you hear a sound from the speakers through the troubleshooter, the speakers themselves are fine. It's probably just settings. What device is selected as your output?

Comment: I am hoping the same but I am really struggling to locate exactly what setting is wrong or needs tweaking. It is set to "Nvidia High Definition Audio"